# OAEP padding with CreateSignature

Tags: c#, .net, rsa

I have some code that creates a digital signature. The message as well as the signature is passed from one system to another. When its received, the signature is verified. This code has been run through Fortify, a service that analyzes code for security vulnerabilities. Fortify is reporting that "The method CreateDigitalSignature() in RSACryptography.cs performs public key RSA encryption without OAEP padding".

I see a parameter on the RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt() method that if true, means to use OAEP padding. But I'm not using Encrypt(). I'm using a RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter to generate and a RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter to verify the signature. So my question is how do I add the padding? Am I supposed to Encrypt the signature before sending it back? See my code where I have marked "IS WHAT I NEED TO DO" where I have added Encrypt and Decrypt calls. Is that what I need to do or something else?

```
// create a digital signature
// returns true if successful. Also, the public key (as an xml string) that can be sent to the other party to verify messages sent
public bool CreateDigitalSignature(string msgToSend, out string publicKey, out string signature)
{
    bool rc = false;
    publicKey = null;
    signature = null;

    try
    {
        // get the hash of the message to send
        byte[] hashValue = GetHashedBytes(msgToSend);

        // Load or generate a public/private key pair.  
        // If it already exists in the key container it will be loaded, otherwise, a new key pair is created
        CspParameters cp = new CspParameters();
        cp.KeyContainerName = KeyStoreContainerName;

        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp);

        // get some info about the key:
        CspKeyContainerInfo info = new CspKeyContainerInfo(cp);

        //Create an RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter object and pass it the RSACryptoServiceProvider to transfer the private key.  
        RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter RSAFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(RSA);

        // Set the hash algorithm
        RSAFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm(hashAlgorithm);  // "SHA256", "SHA1", etc.

        //Create a signature for the hashed value of the data
        byte[] signedHashValue = RSAFormatter.CreateSignature(hashValue);

        // fortify says I need to use OAEP padding
        // IS THIS WHAT I NEED TO DO? Encrypt the signature before I convert it to a string?
        signedHashValue = RSA.Encrypt(signedHashValue, true);

        // convert the signature to a string
        signature = Convert.ToBase64String(signedHashValue);

        // get the public key to return so it can be pased to the receiver and used to verify the signature
        // There are two ways - either export the parameters or create an xml string
        // Using export: This gets public key inforation only (specify true to get both public and private keys)
        // RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = RSA.ExportParameters(false);

        // get a string value of the public key
        publicKey = RSA.ToXmlString(false);

        // demonstration only. how to get the private key
        //string privateKey = RSA.ToXmlString(true);

        rc = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return rc;
}
```

And then to verify the signature:

```
public bool VerifySignature(string origintalData, string publicKeyXml, string signature)
{
    bool verified = false;
    try
    {
        // get the hashed value of the original data. used the specified algoritm stored in the this class
        byte[] hashValue = GetHashedBytes(origintalData);

        // get a byte array of the signature
        byte[] signaturebytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);

        // create a crypto provider
        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

        // set the public key of the crypto service provider
        RSA.FromXmlString(publicKeyXml);

        // create a deformatter
        RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter RSADeformatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(RSA);

        // set the hash algorithm. The sender must use the same algorithm
        RSADeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm(hashAlgorithm);

        // As per Fortify, need to use OAEP padding
        // IS THIS WHAT i NEED TO DO - decrypt the signature before veryfying it?
        signaturebytes = RSA.Decrypt(signaturebytes, true);

        // verify the signature
        verified = RSADeformatter.VerifySignature(hashValue, signaturebytes);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return verified;
}
```

Update:
After upgrading from .Net 4.5.1 to 4.6.1. I can use

```
byte[] signedHashValue = RSA.SignData(bytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1)
```

and the corresponding method

```
RSA.VerifyData(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalData), signaturebytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1)
```

but I can't specify RSASignaturePadding.Pss. If I do I get an exception "Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm."

Also I get the same signature as before, so I feel I haven't really accomplished anything. No way to use AOEP padding?

Comment: OAEP padding is for RSA *encryption*. The modern choice for RSA *signatures* is RSA-PSS.

Comment: In order to use PSS you need to change to `RSACng`.